# Element UI - DateTimePicker how to disable past dates vue.js

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I am using element ui datepicker from [there](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/date-picker). I want to disable past dates.

```html
<el-date-picker
  v-model="form.startDate"
  type="date"
  placeholder="Tarih Seçiniz."
  style="width: 100%"
/>
```

Can you help me to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding a `:disabled-date` attribute in the `<el-date-picker>` element and pass the `boolean` value to this attribute based on the calculation.

```html
<el-date-picker :disabled-date="disabledDate" ...
```

In Script:

```js
const disabledDate = (time: Date) => {
  const date = new Date();
  const previousDate = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
  return time.getTime() < previousDate; 
}
```